# How to obtain the metric tensor of a principal bundle total space given a connection (assuming it is metric compatible) in the total space?

Tags: metric-spaces, principal-bundles, connections

The title says it all.
In a principal bundle I know the connection defined in the total space. How can I calculate the metric that would be compatible with this connection.